# How to reduce par folder size in /tmp?

Tags: perl, rpm, par

I have a perl project packaged by Par::Packer and distribute by RPM on RedHat.

I found that a par-hex{6} directory would be created after each user run my command.

```
$ /tmp
lirian  19M par-6c3973
andy    19M par-6d6a7a
raymond 19M par-726679
john    19M par-736a69
```

Can I reduce the par directory size or use one shared par folder among all user?

More: I've read the instruction on [pp](http://search.cpan.org/~rschupp/PAR-Packer-1.028/lib/pp.pm#OPTIONS) and [PAR::FAQ#RPM](http://search.cpan.org/~rschupp/PAR-1.010/lib/PAR/FAQ.pod#I_want_to_include_a_pp-ed_binary_in_an_RPM_package._How_can_I_make_this_work?).
I use `pp -d` to package the par file.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an not-so-perfect but enough answer.

Now I use "pp -d -T lirian-tool" to package my perl script.

According to [pp-option-page](http://search.cpan.org/%7Erschupp/PAR-Packer-1.028/lib/pp.pm#OPTIONS):

> -T, --tempcache
>
> Set the program unique part of the cache directory name that is used if the program is run without -C. If not set, a hash of the executable is used.
>
> When the program is run, its contents are extracted to a temporary directory. On Unix systems, this is commonly /tmp/par-USER/cache-XXXXXXX. USER is replaced by the name of the user running the program, but "spelled" in hex. XXXXXXX is either a hash of the executable or the value passed to the -T or --tempcache switch.

So now we have /tmp/par-User/cache-lirian-tool. Each user's cache directory may take 20M, which is acceptable.

And you can cleanup the cache by running "pp -c":

> -C, --clean
>
> Clean up temporary files extracted from the application at runtime. By default, these files are cached in the temporary directory; this allows the program to start up faster next time.